# How to verify PDF load in web application by using GEB Spock

Tags: groovy, automation, spock, geb

I need to verify whether the pdf is generated or not when the user navigate to a page. Provably, GEB doesn't support PDF verification. If i still can't verify the pdf contents, i don't mind. But i need to verify the pdf is already there after navigate to that page. Sometimes on that page pdf never generates intead warning message for server errors. So i need to catch that error if the pdf doesnt load. Can you please help? 
FYI, Pdf is not a link on that page. it loads on the fly on that page after navigate to it.

I wrote this code below to navigate to that page:

```
when: 
    "Some Actions"
then: 
    "Click Continue button"

    PbnContinue.click();
    at PDFPage
    Thread.sleep(5000); //Need to have sleep to get enough time to load for testing purpose
    clickPbnSubmit();

expect:
    “assert something”
```

Currently, i am adding some sleep to make sure PDF get enough time to load. But looks like, if they have any server errors, pdf never shows up and my script fails.

Comment: What??? You want to catch a server error in the client??? Anyway, in Groovy, you can call `sleep 5000` instead of `Thread.sleep(5000);`. But you probably shouldn't, this test will be really brittle if you rely on timing. Try waiting for a new page to load (see the book of Geb: http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/browser.html#making_requests). One more thing: you are using Spock wrong. You should have something like `given: "Some setup"`, `when: "Some actions"`, `then: "assert something"`. Do not mix `then` blocks with `expect`!

Comment: I need to catch any errors while pdf doesn't load. How can i verify the pdf has been uploaded or it never loads. fyi, Pdf is shown as part of the webpage inside a frame.

Comment: Did you check this: http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/pages.html#dealing_with_frames ?